# Read xml string from a sql server database with Perl

Tags: xml, perl, ntext

I have a table in which there is a column called XML of type ntext in that I am storing XML string.

When I read that column with Perl script and print it then whole XML string is not printing.

Instead of printing whole XML it only prints

`< T u m o r >
     < p e r s o n U p i > 1 0 1 0 8 1 0 4 3 5 1 6 0 7 < / p e`

Below is the script part.

```
$get_xml_from_log_table = "SELECT XML FROM TR_MIGRATION_LOG WHERE MRN=123";
$xml_from_log_table = $dbh_sql_server->selectrow_array($get_xml_from_log_table);
print $xml_from_log_table ;
```

I am using SQL Server database.

Anybody please help me to get rid of this?

Comment: What Perl module are you using? That code is wrong for a program using `DBI`.

Comment: I am using DBI module. How this can be wrong when I am able to fetch other data. I am facing problem only when I try to fetch the xml string.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't look like it will run, so it's difficult to diagnose what the problem is. It does look like you're evaluating selectrow_array to scalar context, which won't help things.

Instead you should use:

```
my($xml_from_log_table) = $dbh_sql_server->selectrow_array($get_xml_from_log_table);
```